# Edit box template for a forum like website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a forum like website, and I am looking for a custom open source HTML template which can give me a edit box where user and type his inputs, much like what we get when we post a question or answer.

I am sure there would be some handy templates ready and I need not to do all this again, like giving "Bold", "Italics", "Code" etc. button on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ready made text editors available! Do a google search and you will find many!

Eg:

- https://www.tinymce.com/
- http://ckeditor.com/

You could just use one of these and embed it in your web page!

**EDIT**

Quick Start guide on how to use the CKEditor: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

Here's a doc link on how to do the "Getting and saving data" using the CKEditor : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

You would be attaching the CKEditor to a `<textarea>` element. So, when your form is submitted, you could access the data of the CKEditor's content by using the name of the `<textarea>` to which you attached the editor!

Example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="save.php" method="post">
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, the name of the `<textarea>` element to which you attached the CKEditor is `editor1`. So at the PHP side, when the form is submitted you could access the data like this:

```
<?php
    $editor_data = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was good leads and helpful, but looks like they still doesn't solve my problem, finally what user has entered should be submitted, now that's where problem comes that if I access the "textarea" element (I took example of CKEditor) then it doesn't give me formatted output, it is plain text, I am expecting that if user has bolded the text using tht template option, then when I access the element then bolded text should be enclosed in <b> tags, so that same is saved in database. Any ideas?

Comment: @pjj both of those editors are very robust, highly configurable and do all that html structure. Sending to server is part of form submit process and if you don't understand that you need to study some tutorials

Comment: pjj, you need to go through the documentation of these editors! I took the liberty to edit my answer an include an example as well as links to the specific docs. Like @charlietfl said, these editors are powerful and comes loaded with lots of features! You need to spend some time reading the docs or searching in google to get the examples.

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran Thanks